# Aptana 2.0 Eclipse Plugin breaks Eclipse Webpage Editor

Tags: eclipse-plugin, content-type, aptana, html-editor

I have the latest version of Eclipse... so Eclipse Indigo 3.7. When I install the Aptana Studio 2.0 plugin for Eclipse, the Aptana HTML editor works great. However, when I want to switch back to my original Eclipse "Web Page Editor" I get the following alert:

"Unsupported Content Type

Unsupported content type in editor. To associate file extension with a suported content type, please see Contet Types Preference Page"

And when I click "OK" to close the alert, I get a NullPointerException instead of being able to see the editor. Specifically it says:

"Could not open the editor: An unexpected exception was thrown."

Followed by:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.createModelDependentFields(StructuredTextEditor.java:1479)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.update(StructuredTextEditor.java:3091)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.editors.HTMLEditor.sash_createAndAddDesignSourcePage(HTMLEditor.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.editors.HTMLEditor.createPages(HTMLEditor.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2945)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2850)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2842)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2793)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2789)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2773)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu.openEditor(OpenWithMenu.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu$2.handleEvent(OpenWithMenu.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4125)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1457)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1480)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1270)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3971)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? I'm using the Aptana 2.0 plugin for jQuery code assist, and like its HTML editor for that. Unfortunately, I'm using the Play! Web Framework, and Aptana doesn't like their Template Tags (#{} and ${}) when placed within javascript code, and throws errors all over the place. The original simple Eclipse html editor I think worked better in this case.

Or if someone knows how to have Aptana handle the #{} & ${} tags gracefully within javascript/jQuery code.

Comment: That's a matter of opinion.

See here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970595/eclipse-plugin-aptana-errors-on-mac-osx-lion/7030196#7030196][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970595/eclipse-plugin-aptana-errors-on-mac-osx-lion/7030196#7030196

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with Studio 2.0: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-489.  Studio 3.0 handles it better.

Comment: This issue has since been re-introduced, using Aptana Studio 3 and Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler). :-(