# Eclipse plugin Aptana errors on Mac OSX Lion

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aptana

I installed the Aptana plugin (http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install) in my existing Eclipse installation on my Mac OSX Lion. Now my workspace has an error that freezes up Eclipse for about 20 seconds or so with an error as follows:

[Screenshot of error](http://i169.photobucket.com/albums/u227/ejonnybrennan/Dropbox/ScreenShot2011-08-06at80241PM.jpg)

I confirmed that it was the plugin by uninstalling, which completely removes the error. Reinstallation and the same error returns. When I click ok, occasionally Eclipse returns but more often I have to restart it.  Multiple windows of the error appear, as though it is a loop.

Part of the log is listed below.  Many of these similar chunks appear throughout the log.

Any help would be appreciated. Am I missing a required library for this plugin to work?  Something with the apache IOReactorException? Possibly an incompatibility issue with Lion?

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2011-08-06 11:32:42.982
>   !MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
>   !STACK 0
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/nio/reactor/IOReactorException
>       at com.aptana.webserver.core.WebServerCorePlugin.ensureDefaultWebServer(WebServerCorePlugin.java:123)
>       at com.aptana.webserver.core.WebServerCorePlugin.getDefaultWebServerConfiguration(WebServerCorePlugin.java:113)
>       at com.aptana.preview.internal.DefaultPreviewHandler.handle(DefaultPreviewHandler.java:69)
>       at com.aptana.preview.PreviewManager.testEditorInputForPreview(PreviewManager.java:266)
>       at com.aptana.preview.internal.HasPreviewPropertyTester.test(HasPreviewPropertyTester.java:20)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.Property.test(Property.java:58)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TestExpression.evaluate(TestExpression.java:99)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:53)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.WithExpression.evaluate(WithExpression.java:72)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationResultCache.evaluate(EvaluationResultCache.java:74)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.ExpressionAuthority.evaluate(ExpressionAuthority.java:165)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationAuthority.refsWithSameExpression(EvaluationAuthority.java:155)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationAuthority.sourceChanged(EvaluationAuthority.java:129)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.ExpressionAuthority.sourceChanged(ExpressionAuthority.java:311)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.ExpressionAuthority.sourceChanged(ExpressionAuthority.java:290)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.AbstractSourceProvider.fireSourceChanged(AbstractSourceProvider.java:99)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider.checkActivePart(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:401)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider.checkActivePart(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:300)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider.handleCheck(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:286)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider.checkOtherSources(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:858)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider$6.handleEvent(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:842)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1034)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:3782)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1375)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1398)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1379)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowDidBecomeKey(Shell.java:1892)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5031)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:213)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.becomeKeyWindow(Widget.java:324)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.becomeKeyWindow(Shell.java:478)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4863)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(NSWindow.java:190)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.makeKeyAndOrderFront(Shell.java:1130)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setWindowVisible(Shell.java:1740)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.open(Shell.java:1173)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:797)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.open(WorkbenchWindow.java:790)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$66.runWithException(Workbench.java:3658)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3593)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3286)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$31.runWithException(Workbench.java:1567)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3593)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3286)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2548)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.nio.reactor.IOReactorException
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:506)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>       ... 73 more

Comment: I've honestly never seen that error before. A bunch of us develop on Lion. What version of Eclipse are you using, and what else do you have installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this issue on a Windows 7 plugin install of Aptana.

**For me, the resolution ended up being to uninstall EGit.**

Hope the same works for you! For Git functionality, there are many separate tools (even though it would be nice to run everything through Eclipse).

Comment: This happened to be my issue. In looking further, it appears Aptana has their own git support built in so there must be some sort of conflict with EGit installed. Thanks for all the help to everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution of this problem (Ubuntu 11.04, Exlipse Helios) was to replace two jars in plugin directory. I've replaced (manually, of course):

- org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore_4.0.1.jar
- org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore_4.1.0.v201101201700.jar

(as you can see it's a potential source of problems) with the only one:

org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore_4.1.jar

which I found in `httpcomponents-core-4.1-osgi-bin.tar.gz` file at Apache Http Core site (search in "archives").

Maybe only deleting v. 4.0.1 would do, but I did not checked this solution. So far, so good.

Comment: Just deleting v4.0.1 jar didn't work for me. But replacing both as you mentioned with http://archive.apache.org/dist/httpcomponents/httpcore/binary/httpcomponents-core-4.1-osgi-bin.zip did.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is not an "eclipse on Lion" issue:
I see this with Eclipse Helios under Linux amd64 as well every time I open a HTML page in Eclipse - even if I use a text editor and NOT the Aptana HTML editor.
Will try if uninstalling EGit fixes it...

Answer (score 0):

(I hate to be practicing thread necromancy, but this problem is still... a problem.)

I'm getting the same error using Eclipse 4.2 SR1 with the latest Aptana plugin (v3.x?) on Mountain Lion and Java 1.6.0_37. One of my eclipse workspaces is affected, but I can switch to an empty workspace and get Eclipse to start.

The .metadata/.log didn't provide any useful information, but I found something interesting in eclipse/configuration/derby.log:

```
    ============= begin nested exception, level (1) ===========
java.sql.SQLException: Database 'aptanaDB' not found.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.newSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleDBNotFound(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection30.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:243)
    at com.aptana.usage.AptanaDB.shutdown(AptanaDB.java:156)
    at com.aptana.usage.UsagePlugin.stop(UsagePlugin.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.stopWorker(BundleHost.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.suspend(AbstractBundle.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.suspendBundle(Framework.java:1206)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.decFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.shutdown(StartLevelManager.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.suspend(InternalSystemBundle.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.shutdown(Framework.java:692)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.close(Framework.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.shutdown(EclipseStarter.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
============= end nested exception, level (1) ===========
```

I don't know what to do with this information, but perhaps it will help the Aptana team figure out what's going wrong.